# Prolog, given N and find all numbers not divisible by 3 and 5 and these numbers must be smaller than N

Tags: prolog, division

I have problem with find a solution to the problem.
**Divisible/2** predicate examines whether a number N is divisible by one of numbers in the list

```
divisible([H|_],N) :- N mod H =:= 0.
divisible([H|T],N) :- N mod H =\= 0, divisible(T,N).
```

I need to build a predicate find that will find Number < N that are not divisible by the list of numbers 
example input/output:

```
?- find(5, [3,5],Num).
output is : 
Num = 4; Num = 2; Num = 1. False
Here N is 5 and list of number is [3,5]
```

Current Code:

```
findNum(1, LN, Num) :- \+ divisible(LN,1),
                        Num is 1.

findNum(Rank, LN, Num) :- Rank > 1,
                        Num1 is Rank - 1,
                        ( \+ divisible(LN,Num1) -> Num is Num1;
                        findNum(Num1,LN, Num) ).
```

It only prints Num = 4; It never prints 2 and 1 for some reasons
And I am not sure where goes wrong..
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Did you write divisible/2 or was it given as part of the exercise?

Comment: I wrote it......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify the findNum predicate into:

```
findNum(Rank, LN, Num) :- Rank > 1,
                          Num1 is Rank - 1,
                          \+ divisible(LN,Num1) -> Num is Num1.
findNum(Rank, LN, Num) :-  Rank > 1, 
                           Num1 is Rank - 1, 
                           findNum(Num1,LN, Num).
```

For me, it gives the requested answer.

Comment: Thank you, but when I tested it, it gave an extra 1. ie. it prints 4,2,1,1.
Sorry about that, yours runs perfectly..

Answer (score 2):

Done three different ways

---

1. Using recursion

```
find_rec(0,_,[]) :- !.
find_rec(N0,Possible_divisors,[N0|Successful_divisors]) :-
    divisible(Possible_divisors,N0),
    N is N0 - 1,
    find_rec(N,Possible_divisors,Successful_divisors).
find_rec(N0,Possible_divisors,Successful_divisors) :-
    \+ divisible(Possible_divisors,N0),
    N is N0 - 1,
    find_rec(N,Possible_divisors,Successful_divisors).
```

Example run

```
?- find_rec(5,[3,5],Num).
Num = [5, 3] ;
false.
```

---

2. Using partition

```
find_par(N,Possible_divisors,Successful_divisors) :-
    findall(Ns,between(1,N,Ns),List),
    partition(partition_predicate(Possible_divisors),List,Successful_divisors,_).

partition_predicate(L,N) :-
    divisible(L,N).
```

Example run

```
?- find_par(5,[3,5],Num).
Num = [3, 5].
```

---

3. Using conditional ( -> ; )

```
find_con(0,_,[]) :- !.
find_con(N0,Possible_divisors,Result) :-
    (
        divisible(Possible_divisors,N0)
    ->
        Result = [N0|Successful_divisors]
    ;
        Result = Successful_divisors
    ),
    N is N0 - 1,
    find_con(N,Possible_divisors,Successful_divisors).
```

Example run

```
?- find_con(5,[3,5],Num).
Num = [5, 3].
```

---

It would be nice to see some test cases for divisible/2 to quickly understand how it works.

```
:- begin_tests(divisible).

divisible_test_case_generator([13,1],13).
divisible_test_case_generator([20,10,5,4,2,1],20).
divisible_test_case_generator([72,36,24,18,12,9,8,6,4,3,2,1],72).
divisible_test_case_generator([97,1],97).
divisible_test_case_generator([99,33,11,9,3,1],99).

test(1,[nondet,forall(divisible_test_case_generator(List,N))]) :-
    divisible(List,N).

:- end_tests(divisible).
```

Running of tests

```
?- make.
% c:/users/groot/documents/projects/prolog/so_question_177 compiled 0.00 sec, 0 clauses
% PL-Unit: divisible ..... done
% All 5 tests passed
true.
```

---

Some feedback about your code.

1. Typically the formatting of a predicate starts a new line after `:-`
2. When using a `;` operator, it is better to put it on a line by itself so that it is very obvious, many programmers have spent hours looking for bugs because a `;` was seen as a `,` and not understood correctly.

```
findNum(1, LN, Num) :-
    \+ divisible(LN,1),
    Num is 1.

findNum(Rank, LN, Num) :-
    Rank > 1,
    Num1 is Rank - 1,
    (
        \+ divisible(LN,Num1)
    ->
        Num is Num1
    ;
        findNum(Num1,LN, Num)
    ).
```

---

Where the bug is in your code is here for the `<true case>`

```
    ->
        Num is Num1
```

you did not recurse for the next value like you did for the `<false case>`

```
    ;
        findNum(Num1,LN, Num)
```

Comment: Num should be 4,2,1 which is not divisible by any of the number in the list

Comment: But I got your ideas and thanks for your feedback. That's really helpful :)

Comment: @zxcisnoias I will fix the code if I knew what you meant by `Num should be 4,2,1 which is not divisible by any of the number in the list` Also if you gave more examples I can add a set of test cases. Having one example makes it hard to always get the code correct.